# input parallel capacitors for rectifier in flyback

Tags: capacitor, parallel, flyback, input

When should we use multiple parallel capacitors instead of a single one in input rectifier topologies of switching converters such as flyback?? What are the advantages and disadvantages?? thankfully[image]

Comment: Price? Size? Availability? Mechanical packaging?

Comment: No limitation. Only functionality.

Comment: Then very little difference. ESR and ESL can differ between a single large or multiple small ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When should we use multiple parallel capacitors instead of a single
> one in input rectifier topologies

The need is more generic than specific to flyback and typically is driven by availability.

The specific capacitance is usually determined via analysis (simulation or calculations). However practical availability might constrain what you can procure.  What if your analysis say you need 180uF but the preferred value manufactured is 100uF ?

Likewise other constraints might result in the physical design being made out of multiple parallel as oppose to a single

1. There is a preferred part used within a company to manage their inventory
2. There is a height constraint limiting the ability to use certain types of capacitors.

There is also the ripple current and inrush capability. A single capacitor might have a limit that is below the anticipated design and thus parallel capacitors would be required to realize the current capability needed by the design

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two main reasons for splitting the input capacitance into two, lifetime and filtering.

**Lifetime**: The lifetime of the bulk / input capacitor is one of the main bottlenecks of such power supplies, and it is mostly a function of the ripple current experienced by the capacitor and its operating temperature. This especially important when designing for industrial applications, which expect a power supply to have a long longevity (15 ~ 20 years). In order to reduce the ripple current, more capacitors (with lower capacitance and higher ripple current capability) are used.

**Filtering**: It is well known that if not properly designed, flyback converters couple a lot of noise to the input and vice-versa. By splitting the input capacitor into two for example, you could build a PI filter with an additional inductor between them. However, this leads to a higher complexity when selecting the capacitors due to their ripple-current unbalance. Essentially the capacitor sitting closer to the transformer will experience a higher ripple current, because the inductor will limit the current delivered by the capacitor sitting closer to the mains.